# Viewing the coefficients/weights of a pickled trained model in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle

I have trained a SVM in Scikit-learn a few months back:

```
# Create standardizer
standardizer = StandardScaler()

# Create logistic regression
lsvc = SVC(C=0.1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)

# Create a pipeline that standardizes, then runs Support Vector Machine
svc_pipeline = make_pipeline(standardizer,lsvc)
```

and I have pickled the model like this:

```
# Save Trained Model
with open('WF_SVC_Final.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(svc_pipeline, fid)
```

Now, I have loaded the the pickled model like this:

```
WF_SVC_Final = pickle.load(open('WF_SVC_Final.pkl', 'rb'))
```

I can use the pickled model to classify new data by invoking this:

```
WF_SVC_Final.predict(x)
```

But I am trying to view/check the coefficients of the pickled model through .coef_ attribute but for some reason this does not work:

```
WF_SVC_Final.coef_
```

I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'coef_'

Anyone know how to get around this? Thanks

Comment: You need use the correct name for the desired attribute, or you need to load an object that really has that attribute.  Often these attribute errors are caused by have the wrong class of object.  I don't know whether a `Pipeline` really does have a `coef_` attribute or not.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html.  The example on this page, `>>> coef = anova_svm[-1].coef_` suggests that an 'element' of the `pipeline` has this attribute, not the `pipeline` itself.

Comment: but once I pickled the pipeline model, how do I access "lsvc" attributes from the pipeline? any ideas? thanks

Comment: I can only tell you what I learn from the documentation.

Comment: If you think the below answer helped you resolve your problem, I kindly request you to accept it an answer, as it will help others to find the right answer if they also face similar issues. Thanks in advance! For more details please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just that you need to call the `named_steps` inside inside the pipeline and call `coef` on top of it. I have modified your code as below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle 

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2,
                       n_informative=4, weights=[0.7, 0.3],
                       random_state=0)

standardizer = StandardScaler()

# Create support vector classifier
lsvc = SVC(C=0.1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
           decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
           max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
           tol=0.001, verbose=False)

# Create a pipeline that standardizes, then runs Support Vector Machine  
svc_pipeline = make_pipeline(standardizer,lsvc)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
svc_pipeline.fit(x_train,y_train)

with open('WF_SVC_Final.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(svc_pipeline, fid)

WF_SVC_Final = pickle.load(open('WF_SVC_Final.pkl', 'rb'))

coefficients = WF_SVC_Final.named_steps["svc"].coef_   #since svc is the name of the estimator we call it here
```

And now when we print `coefficients` we get

```
array([[ 0.02914615,  0.02835727, -0.0476559 , -0.03579271,  0.07187892,
    -0.10166647,  0.25455972, -0.02468286,  0.07035736, -0.0427572 ,
    -0.06497132, -0.1014921 , -0.01929861, -0.00833354, -0.04557688,
     0.06657225, -0.05579179,  0.24851723,  0.29399611,  0.04916833]])
```